# Integral of exponent $\iint\limits_0^\infty e^{(t_1 x+t_2 y -y) }\ dy\ dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Please help me to solve this equation. I have attempted to answer this one however I always arrived at the wrong answer. Instead of having the positive sign, I always ended with its negative answer. Please help.

$ M(t_1,t_2)= \int\limits_0^\infty \int\limits_0^\infty e^{(t_1 x+t_2 y -y) }\ dy\ dx$
 I always ended with this one $ = \frac1{(t_1+t_2-1)(t_2-1)} $

Comment: Are you sure about the limits of integration? I get a different answer.

Comment: Yes I am, but I am not sure with  my answer.=)

Comment: Is $M(t_1,t_2)$ a moment generating function of certain distribution? The integral is separable so that we can rewrite as
\begin{align}
M(t_1,t_2)&=\int_0^\infty e^{-(1-t_2)y}\,dy \int_0^\infty e^{t_1x}\,dx
\end{align}
where the integral exist for $t_1<0$ and $t_2<1$.

Comment: could you help me integrate this one.. is my answer above correct?

Comment: I get $$M(t_1,t_2)=\frac{1}{t_1(t_2-1)}$$

Comment: I will review mine. thanks

Comment: @Amastasiya-Romanova you have some restrictions too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's integrate with respect to $x$ first.  $$\int\limits_0^\infty \int\limits_0^\infty e^{(t_1x+t_2y-y) }\ dy\ dx = \int\limits_0^\infty \left( \int\limits_0^\infty e^{(t_1x+t_2y-y) }\ dx\right)dy \\ = \int\limits_0^\infty \left(\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{t_1}\left[e^{(t_1x+t_2y-y) }  \right]\Big|_0^N \right)dy$$ Before evaluating this limit, we can see that $t_1 \neq 0$ as it would mean division by zero. Second, if $t_1>0$ then $e^{t_1x}$ will diverge to infinity as $x \to \infty$, hence $e^{t_1x+t_2y-y}$ (could) diverge. So we require $t_1<0$ to guarantee the existence of our limit. Thus,  $$\int\limits_0^\infty \left(\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{t_1}\left[e^{(t_1x+t_2y-y)}\right] \Big|_0^N \right)dy = \int\limits_0^\infty \left(\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{t_1}\left[e^{t_1x}e^{y(t_2-1)}  \right]\Big|_0^N\right)dy \\ = \int\limits_0^\infty \left( \frac{1}{t_1}\left[0-e^{y(t_2-1)}  \right]\right)dy \\ = \frac{-1}{t_1}\int\limits_0^\infty e^{y(t_2-1)}dy \\ =\frac{-1}{t_1}\left(\frac{1}{t_2-1}  \lim_{N \to \infty} \left[e^{y(t_2-1)} \right] \Big|_0^N \right)$$ Again we have to be careful with the value of $t_2$. If $t_2 = 1$ we will have division by zero, and if $t_2>1$ then $e^{y(t_2-1)}$ will diverge to infinity as $y \to \infty$. Hence we require $t_2<1$ for the limit to exist. Now we can conclude that $$\frac{-1}{t_1}\left(\frac{1}{t_2-1}  \lim_{N \to \infty} \left[e^{y(t_2-1)} \right] \Big|_0^N \right) = \frac{-1}{t_1}\frac{1}{t_2-1}\left[0-1 \right] \\ = \frac{-1}{t_1}\frac{-1}{t_2-1} \\ = \frac{1}{t_1(t_2-1)}$$  So $$M(t_1, t_2) = \frac{1}{t_1(t_2-1)} \quad \text{for all} \space t_1<0 \space \text{and}\space  t_2<1$$